# linkedin js api - "get my connections" issue

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

here is the issue we have:

We make an app using linkedin js api. We are getting connections of a person that logs in on a site with this:

```
IN.API.Connections("me").fields("id", "formattedName", "pictureUrl", "publicProfileUrl", "siteStandardProfileRequest").result(function(result, metadata){});
```

While testing it's working fine - we've tested it wit five different people, but with one (mine particulary) we have an issue (https://www.linkedin.com/pub/emil-mikhailov/87/481/726). And the actual difference is that I have around 200 connections, but mine testers- only around 20-50.

Response gives us only  __total, just the amount of contacts. But via console apigee we recieve the list. adress of  ajax quest https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections:(id,formatted-name,picture-url,public-profile-url,site-standard-profile-request)

appreciate your help

Comment: I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but are you aware that this API will no longer be available as of May 12th, 2015?  

https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

Comment: Thank you Justin - but I didn't get - they will close the access to person's connections at all?

Comment: Connections will only be available to applications that are part of an approved Partner Program, so the call you are currently making in this example will no longer be openly available. https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an accurate answer but according to https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api it says

> You cannot "browse connections." That is, you can only get the connections of the user who granted your application access. You cannot get connections of that user's connections (2nd degree connections).

So your application may be only displaying your own first degree connections

Comment: Can i have the complete set of code to get connections?